# Loop through a range to open corresponding files

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I have a list of *.xlsm file names on a sheet named "DB" in range E961 to E1010 (50 rows) and I'm trying to create a macro that runs through this list and open the corresponding files in the set directory, runs some code and close the file, moving on to the next file on the list - repeating this operation every 5 minutes.

The directory contains 400+ xlsm files, and the list in E961 will typically be less than 50 files - so I'm not trying to open all the files in the directory. That already happens once a day at a set time.

But I am trying to open these "shortlisted" files and update them every 5 minutes for example. I tried different combinations of code but can't seem to get it working.

The main file containing this code is also in the same directory to allow relative linking to the other 400+ files, hence the ThisWorkbook.Path code.

Edited code below:

```
Sub UPDATE()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB")
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Set inputRange = .Range("E961", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
End With

Dim directory As String: directory = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
Dim fileName As String
Dim r As Range
Dim xlwb As Workbook
For Each r In inputRange
    If r <> vbNullString Then
        fileName = Dir(directory & r & ".xl??*")
        Set xlwb = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)


                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

                    If Range("A4") > Sheets("DB").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0) Then

                    Worksheets("DB").Range("A4:L4").Select
                    Worksheets("DB").Range("A4").Activate
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("DB").Select
                    Sheets("DB").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1). _
                    PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                    Else
                    End If

                    If Range("A4") = Sheets("DB").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0) Then

                    Worksheets("DB").Range("A4:L4").Select
                    Worksheets("DB").Range("A4").Activate
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("DB").Select
                    Sheets("DB").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0). _
                    PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                    SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                    End If

        xlwb.Close True
    End If
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The error comes from "Set xlwb = (sht.Cells(Row, 1).Value)" because it is trying to open a sheet as a workbook, but I have no idea how to fix it... or everything is wrong ...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to use `Workbooks.Open` to actually open the workbook.

Comment: You are also missing the `sht` reference on your `inputRange`, just at the beginning, or it will be the size for your `sht` but referencing the active sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece it should work thought it will only open and close workbooks until you give it some code to work them:

```
Option Explicit
Sub UPDATE()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'if you are only using here your wb and sht variables, use a With, there is no need to use variables
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB")
        Dim inputRange As Range
        'It is preferable to do xlUp because you could find some empty cells in between.
        Set inputRange = .Range("E961", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Dim directory As String: directory = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim xlwb As Workbook
    For Each r In inputRange
        If r <> vbNullString Then
            fileName = Dir(directory & r & ".xl??*") 'don't know if your cell has the extension
            Set xlwb = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)
            'some code
            xlwb.Close False 'False won't save the workbook, use True if you want it to be saved.
        End If
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to work first time! Cool, but even with xlwb.Close TRUE, the files aren't being saved. I disable screenupdating to make sure the code runs the files, and it does, but it seems open and close without saving changes. The "some code" was added to your solution just in case it is doing something it is not supposed to. Running that exact 'some code from within the opened file works 100%

Comment: @Martin add the code to your original question please.

Comment: The 'some code essentially updates the last entry if it matches the current date, or adds a new line with values for the current date. So I can't see how it would prevent saving

Comment: I saw on your edit that there were a ton of unreferenced code... maybe it wasn't changing that workbook but something else... you should try to use the full reference in all your `Cells`,  `Ranges`, `Sheets` and so..

Comment: Updated the original post. The opened workbook references data from the main workbook in A4 to L4, then the code simply copies those values from A4 to L4 down into the DB sheet by updating the values if the date already exists, or if not, adds a new line with the latest date and data from A4 to L4. The list of entries are then processed in the opened workbook and linked back to the main workbook. I split this operation because there would be too much data to run everything in a single file. The folder size is 140MB already.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working perfectly now. Thank you for the help Damian. I'm not that familiar with VB, what improvements are you reffering to with your last comment - an example perhaps? Thanks again.